# Autocad installation error

Tags: windows-8, autocad

I'm trying to install Autocad 2014 on windows 8. when I finish installation and try to open it I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Unhandled Access violation reading 0x0020 exception at d53a4972h
```

Ok I now know this problem is from autodesk. why is it happening, what should I do?

## Edit:

I did and still not getting any response. How much should I wait?

Comment: Is the error dialog generated by Autodesk or Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound how can I know?

Answer (score 1):

try contacting your supplier for help Or send an error report to the autodesk company.

Comment: Since does not provide a direct solution, you should post this as a comment to the question.

Comment: I can't comment. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoCAD for windows 8.1, you should do the following steps:

1. Uninstall 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable'
2. Download and Install .Net 3.5 Framework for 8.1.
3. install AutoCAD 2014.

The reason for this is that AutoCAD is that Autodesk has not officially supported Win8.1, and it installs an older version of `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable`. Install AutoCAD and let it install its own older version of the framework, then later after AutoCAD is running, install the newer "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable".

Download here:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Sources:

- http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2013-2014/AutoCAD-2014-and-Windows-8-1/td-p/4632085
- http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Installation-Licensing/Some-Products-Fail-to-Install-Result-1603/td-p/3382347